# Add and rename property conditionally in Ramda without using a lense

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I need to fix properties for an object in ramda.js. I would like to do not use lenses.

Having the following data I need:

If objects in array properties in `a` and `b` an others

- do not have property "animationTimingFunction" add property key "easing" with value `ease`
- do have property "animationTimingFunction" rename this property to "easing" and keep the value as it is.

Input data:

```
let data = {
    "a": [{
        "opacity": "1",
        "offset": "0"
    }, {
        "opacity": "0",
        "offset": "0.25",
        "animationTimingFunction": "linear"
    }, {
        "opacity": "1",
        "offset": "0.5"
    },
    "b": [{
        "transform": "scale3d(1, 1, 1)",
        "offset": "0"
    }, {
        "transform": "scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)",
        "offset": "0.5"
    }, {
        "transform": "scale3d(1, 1, 1)",
        "offset": "1"
    }]
};
```

Output should be:

```
let data = {
    "a": [{
        "opacity": "1",
        "offset": "0",
        "easing": "ease"
    }, {
        "opacity": "0",
        "offset": "0.25",
        "easing": "linear"
    }, {
        "opacity": "1",
        "offset": "0.5",
        "easing": "ease"
    },
    "b": [{
        "transform": "scale3d(1, 1, 1)",
        "offset": "0",
        "easing": "ease"
    }, {
        "transform": "scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05)",
        "offset": "0.5",
        "easing": "ease"
    }, {
        "transform": "scale3d(1, 1, 1)",
        "offset": "1",
        "easing": "ease"
    }]
};
```

As a start I have tried but I miss the condition part:

```
    let convertEasing = (data) =>{
        let convert = data => R.assoc('easing', 'linear');
        let result = R.map(R.map(convert(data)), data)
        return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just

```
const alter = obj => {
  const ease = prop('animationTimingFunction', obj) || 'ease';
  return dissoc('animationTimingFunction', assoc('easing', ease, obj));
}

map(map(alter))(data);
```

You could do it points-free if you choose:

```
const alter = pipe(
  chain(
    assoc('easing'),
    pipe(prop('animationTimingFunction'), defaultTo('ease')),
  ),
  dissoc('animationTimingFunction')
)
```

But to my mind that loses in readability.

You can see [either](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22a%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22opacity%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22opacity%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220.25%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22animationTimingFunction%22%3A%20%22linear%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22opacity%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220.5%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22b%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22transform%22%3A%20%22scale3d%281%2C%201%2C%201%29%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22transform%22%3A%20%22scale3d%281.05%2C%201.05%2C%201.05%29%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220.5%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22transform%22%3A%20%22scale3d%281%2C%201%2C%201%29%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%221%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20alter%20%3D%20obj%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20ease%20%3D%20prop%28%27animationTimingFunction%27%2C%20obj%29%20%7C%7C%20%27ease%27%3B%0A%20%20return%20dissoc%28%27animationTimingFunction%27%2C%20assoc%28%27easing%27%2C%20ease%2C%20obj%29%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Amap%28map%28alter%29%29%28data%29%0A) [version](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22a%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22opacity%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22opacity%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220.25%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22animationTimingFunction%22%3A%20%22linear%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22opacity%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220.5%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22b%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22transform%22%3A%20%22scale3d%281%2C%201%2C%201%29%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22transform%22%3A%20%22scale3d%281.05%2C%201.05%2C%201.05%29%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%220.5%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22transform%22%3A%20%22scale3d%281%2C%201%2C%201%29%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22offset%22%3A%20%221%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20alter%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20chain%28%0A%20%20%20%20assoc%28%27easing%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pipe%28prop%28%27animationTimingFunction%27%29%2C%20defaultTo%28%27ease%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%29%2C%0A%20%20dissoc%28%27animationTimingFunction%27%29%0A%29%0A%0A%0Amap%28map%28alter%29%29%28data%29%0A) on the Ramda REPL.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I actually tried using R.cond but your version is much more clear.